# Completion handler with swift

Tags: xml, swift, post, callback, completionhandler

I'm currently learning swift and I'm trying to understand an error since some hours now. I'm trying to get an xml file from a php script thanks to queries and I'm using a completion handler to get the result of those queries as a callback.

Problem is that I'm not comfortable with these techniques and it says that arguments are missing.

Here is the function that uses the completion handler:

```
func connect(completion: (String) -> ())
    {
    let password : String = "psw"
    let login : String = "log"
    let postString : String = "login=\(login)&password=\(password)"
    let urlString = "http://www.mydomain.fr/script.php"
    var output : String = ""
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        output = responseString as! String
    }
    task.resume()
    completion(output)
}
```

And here's the piece of code where I call this function:

```
    func misctest()
{
    let dbc : dataBaseCloner = dataBaseCloner()
    let output: String
    connect(completion : { (output) in
        print(output)
    })
}
```

This piece of code displays this error about the call to connect:

```
>>>Missing argument for parameter #2 in call
```

What did I do wrong? Why does it want two parameters?

Thank you very much for your help.

Elbattore

Comment: This will not repair your error but you have to move "completion(output)"  to your task completion, because it's async and without that your output will be always empty

Answer (score 1):

I've copy pasted your code and it's working without any error. Try to turn off and on the Xcode.

Also you have to move `completion(output)` to your task completion, because it's async and without that your output will be always empty:

```
(...)
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    output = responseString as! String
    completion(output)
    }
task.resume()
(...)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, even if I updated Xcode, it doesn't work. and starts doing errors even more complicated

Answer (score 0):

this is super strange. I just tried again, I placed the completion at the right place as you asked and I rebooted Xcode, updated it and rebooted my computer, I still have this error: missing argument for parameter #2 in call. This time if I click the error it proposes me something, to add two new parameters like :

```
func misctest()
{
    let dbc : dataBaseCloner = dataBaseCloner()
    let output: String
    connect({ (output) in
        print(output)
    }, <#UnsafePointer<sockaddr>!#>, <#socklen_t#>)
    print("working!")
}
```

but then it's not working and says me:

```
cannot convert value of type '(Any)->()' to expected argument type'int32'
```

This is so weird.